# jquery to disable LI on the basis of hidden field within LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Below I have some jsp code and jquery to disable `li` on the basis of hidden input value within same `li`, but it's not working.

```js
$("li#menuli:has('input'):contains('myvalue)").addClass('disabled');
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
 <s:iterator status="idx" value="VO.List">
 <li id="menuli" ><s:hidden name="test[%{#idx.index}]" id="test[%{#idx.index}]" value="${myvalue})"/>
  <a class="header-nav-link" href="#">${VO.Name}</a>                                     
 </li>
  </s:iterator>
</ul>
```

Comment: Disabling a `li` element? How do you disable a list item?

Comment: @Vohuman seems he wants to make it look like disabled by adding the class `disabled`

Comment: `$('li').find("[value='myvalue']").addClass('disabled')`?

Comment: missing `'` in `contains('myvalue')`

Comment: You need any of these 2, `"li#menuli:has(input):contains('myvalue')"` or `"li#menuli:has(input[value='myvalue'])"`

Comment: did the `<li>` just got closed immediately after `id="menuli"`?

Comment: Also the `id` should be unique, use `class` for group of elements

Comment: Morcen i could see it is able to find and selector but how to disable anchor link instead of hidden box current its adding class to hidden not the link.
<input type="hidden" name="test[0]" value="myvalue" id="test[0]" class="disabled">
 <a class="header-nav-link" href="#">my Link</a>
</li>

Comment: Thx could able to resolve the issue thx a lot for guide

Comment: Next time make sure that your title, description and your example are all well-formed, otherwise we are all wasting time to help you. You wanted to disable the `li` you said, it appears that what you really want is to add `disable` class to the anchor. Don't be in a hurry to post a question next time.

Answer (score 0):

`:contains` is for text, not form control values

Can use `filter()`

```
$("#menu li:has('input')").filter(function(){
     return $(this).find('input').val() === 'myvalue';
}).addClass('disabled');
```

Note that ID's must be unique by defintiion

Comment: Thx this is working and resolved my issue. thx for all Seniors for helping great!!!

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that there are lots of syntax errors in your given example, but provided that everything is correct, you can search using the value by simply using the following selector:

`$('li[value="myvalue"]').addClass('disabled');`